# Which is the most functional way to fill multidimensional array from textfile?

Tags: arrays, scala, file, apache-spark

I have a `textfile`:

```
0.1  0.0
0.2  0.1
0.3  0.0
0.0  0.4
```

And i want to fill a `2-dimension array` with it.

The wanted result would look like:

```
RDD(Array(Array(0.1, 0.0), Array(0.2, 0.1), Array(0.3, 0.0), Array(0.0, 0.4)))
```

Knowing that in `spark`, the `textfile` is read per line, what would be the most functional way to fill it?

I've tried several ways, but everytime I end up in:

```
RDD (Array(Array(0.1, 0.0)
     Array(Array(0.2, 0.1)
     Array(Array(0.3, 0.0)
     Array(Array(0.0, 0.4))
```

I am thinking about using something like `foldLeft`, but i think there should be an easier way. Am i wrong?

What i have tried:

```
val V = sc.textFile("file.txt")
          .map(_.split(" ")
                .map(x=> Array(x.toDouble))
                .grouped(2)
                .map(_.flatten).toArray)
```

Comment: If you want an array in the memory of a single node, then what does it all have to do with Spark? You probably should show the code that you are trying to fix, that would prevent guessing and speculation -> [mcve].

Comment: Ok thanks, i edited it.

Comment: I don't know what all those `grouped` and `flatten` are supposed to be good for, but since you never invoke `collect`, there is absolutely no reason why those separate rows would ever end up on a single node, let alone in the same array. An `Array` is a really simple data structure in the memory of a *single* computer. If your data is spread across a datacenter, it cannot possibly be in one array.

Comment: I understand what you are talking about, the thing is that these data are previously collected, processed, broadcast and saved to file. I want them to compare with new RDD, so collect could not help me. But thank you, i will figure out another way!

Answer (score 0):

You can be benefited by using `wholeTextFiles`

```
val V = sc.wholeTextFiles("file.txt")
  .map(_._2.split("\n")
    .map(_.split(" ")
      .map(_.trim.toDouble)))
```

which should give you your desired output as

```
//V: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Array[Double]]]
```

and **if you have multiple spaces in the middle of doubles** then you can use `\\s+` as

```
val V = sc.wholeTextFiles("file.txt")
  .map(_._2.split("\n")
    .map(_.split("\\s+")
      .map(_.trim.toDouble)))
```

I hope the answer is helpful